# Strange Sculpting Colors from Mesh

Tags: mesh, sculpting, sculpt

I am learning sculpting in Blender 2.9 and as I merged two meshes together to practice the remesh tool, it led to this strange, separate color. How do I get rid of this? Should I get rid of this? Is it really a problem?

Comment: Looks like you've got a second layer of mesh under it... or a different object altogether. Go into edit mode, click some random vertice, press CMD+L or or something like that to select all connected. Then press P to seperate and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far a I know... face set's are automatically created when you merge/boolean two or more objects objects.
you can grow either of those face sets by selecting draw brush, you can see more info [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/editing/face_sets.html).

I was annoyed by these things thinking it was a problem when I started sculpting.
Turns out they are very useful when you have a big or complex mesh while sculpting.